# Is there a (tournament) standard for character picks?

Tags: citadels

The Dark City expansion increases replay value for casual play by adding extra character roles. But what about tournament play? Is there a combination of characters that is commonly used in a tournament setting? Or maybe there's a character (or combination of characters) that's banned/excluded from official events?

There already is a (somewhat subjective) [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/what-is-the-most-balanced-competitive-character-set-in-citadels) about balance and preference. I'm looking for a source with authority, like a publisher, or (inter)national tournament host, or anything that comes close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; FFG don't host official Citadels tournament events (evidence includes [this page](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2015/10/2/announcing-2016-store-championships/) which lists games supported for store championship events).

The only tournament I could find online run by players was [this one](http://anime-kpi.net/bbs/index.php/topic,3216.0.html), which used only the base game (not the Dark City cards).